# Which design pattern can I use in my algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I would like to create two algorithm with design pattern approach. Robot should clean and return to the initial position.

After clean the room, i need the cleaned path also.

I am planing to use the Command pattern.But one doubt, requirement says both clean and return algorithem should be interchangable and required two algorithem...so i havae a doubt Stratagy is better than Command pattern?

As per command pattern I can store all the executed commands in a List and find out the path. But still I have a doubt which pattern will be best(requirement says two ago required).

Please see the design , clean and return from different interface so i think it is difficult to use factory to make interchangable...

```
public interface ICleaningAlgorithm {
    void Clean(IRobot robot);
}

public interface IReturnAlgorithm {
   void Return(IRobot robot);
}
Example classes (without implementation):

public class CleaningAlgorithm : ICleaningAlgorithm {
    public void Clean(IRobot robot) {
        /* pseudocode from the post */
    }
}

public class ReturnAlgorithm {
   public void Return(IRobot robot) {
       /* some shortest path algorithm */
   }
}
```

[image]  Design UML image attached

Comment: You shouldn't set out with the goal of using design patterns. You should design well - patterns will become apparent.

Comment: Oh. And patterns are not mutually exclusive. You can use more than one pattern at the same time.

Comment: I have updated the question with my design.clean and return from different interface so how can i do interchangable?

Comment: i have attached the UML any suggestion to improve?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have two algorithms that are interchangeable at runtime, then you should look into the `Factory` pattern, and the `Command` Pattern. As Oded said, design patterns are not mutually exclusive.

**For example**

```
public interface Command
{
   // First, you define a common interface for all commands.
   public void execute();
}

public class Command1 implements Command
{
   // Implement the execute method.
   public void execute()
   {
      // Run some code in here.
   }
}

 public class Command2 implements Command
{
   // Implement the execute method for the second command.
   public void execute()
   {
      // Run some more code in here.
   }
}
```

So, now you've defined a common interface for your commands, which means they can be referenced like this:

```
Command com = new Command2();
// This is an important property!
```

Now you will implement your `Factory` class:

```
public class CommandFactory
{

     public static int ALGO_1 = 1;
     public static int ALGO_2 = 2;

     public Command getInstance(int discriminator)
     {
          // Check the value, and if it matches a pre-defined value..
          switch(discriminator)
          {
              case ALGO_1:
                          return new Command1();
                          break;
              case ALGO_2:
                          return new Command2();
                          break;
          }
     }
}
```

This means you now have a more flexible way of generating these classes, and you can use this class as follows:

```
CommandFactory factory = new CommandFactory();

Command com = factory.getInstance(CommandFactory.ALGO_1);
// You've just generated algorithm 1.
com.execute();
// And you've just ran the code in algorithm 1.
```

**Edit in response**

My question is, why define different interfaces? Why not have it like:

```
public interface Algorithm {
   void execute(IRobot robot);
}

public class CleaningAlgorithm : Algorithm {
    public void execute(IRobot robot) {
    /* pseudocode from the post */
    }
}

public class ReturnAlgorithm : Algorithm {
   public void execute(IRobot robot) {
       /* some shortest path algorithm */
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be interchangeable and also end of first algorithem should print the path(second algo will give the path).So can i implement command pattern and each command i can store in a list<command> also do a reverse for finding the path(second algorithem)?

Comment: I have updated the question with my design.clean and return from different interface so how can i do interchangable?

Comment: Hi Chris i have attached the UML image..Any suggestion

Comment: That UML represents **exactly** what I've given you. A common interface, two classes that implement that interface and a `Factory` class to generate those classes.

Comment: i have one more question,We have a external interface that i should not implement but i can use. We have a fake class implemented from this for test.I am using through Dependency Injection.Few properties in the interfaces are read only(Only get ) but ultimately we need to print this property for Output.How can i assaign value to this?